# Loop though ElasticSearch documents source array in painless

Tags: loops, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have the following ElasticSearch data structure for products in a webshop:

```json
{
  "_index": "vue_storefront_catalog_1_product_1617378559",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_source": {
    "configurable_children": [
      {
        "price": 49.99,
        "special_price": 34.99,
        "special_from_date": "2020-11-27 00:00:00",
        "special_to_date": "2020-11-30 23:59:59",
        "stock": {
          "qty": 0,
          "is_in_stock": false,
          "stock_status": 0
        }
      }
      {
        "price": 49.99,
        "special_price": null,
        "special_from_date": null,
        "special_to_date": null,
        "stock": {
          "qty": 0,
          "is_in_stock": false,
          "stock_status": 0
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Using the following mapping:

```json
{
  "vue_storefront_catalog_1_product_1614928276" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "configurable_children" : {
          "properties" : {
            "price" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "special_from_date" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
            },
            "special_price" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "special_to_date" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a Elasticsearch query to filter out only products that are in sale, that means: the special_price must be lower than the price and the current date must be between the special_from_date and special_to_date.

This is the Painless script I have created:

```
  boolean hasSale = false;

  long timestampNow = new Date().getTime();
  if (doc.containsKey('configurable_children.special_from_date') && !doc['configurable_children.special_from_date'].empty) {
    long timestampSpecialFromDate = doc['configurable_children.special_from_date'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    if (timestampSpecialFromDate > timestampNow) {
      hasSale = false;
    }
  } else if (doc.containsKey('configurable_children.special_to_date') && !doc['configurable_children.special_to_date'].empty) {
    long timestampSpecialToDate = doc['configurable_children.special_to_date'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    if (timestampSpecialToDate < timestampNow) {
      hasSale = false;
    }
  } else if (doc.containsKey('configurable_children.stock.is_in_stock') && doc['configurable_children.stock.is_in_stock'].value == false) {
      hasSale = false;
  } else if (1 - (doc['configurable_children.special_price'].value / doc['configurable_children.price'].value) > params.fraction) {
    hasSale = true;
  }

  return hasSale
```

This returns the product as soon as one of the configurable_children has met the criteria to be a sale product. This is incorrect, because I need to loop through the whole set op configurable_children to determine if it's a sale product. How can I make sure all children are taken into the calculation? With a loop?

---

Here is the new query as suggested by Joe in the answers:

```json
GET vue_storefront_catalog_1_product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                int allEntriesAreTrue(def arrayList) {
                  return arrayList.stream().allMatch(Boolean::valueOf) == true ? 1 : 0
                } 
                
                ArrayList childrenAreMatching = [];
                
                long timestampNow = params.timestampNow;
                
                ArrayList children = params._source['configurable_children'];
                
                if (children == null || children.size() == 0) {
                  return allEntriesAreTrue(childrenAreMatching);
                }
                
                for (config in children) {
                  if (!config.containsKey('stock')) {
                    childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                    continue;
                  } else if (!config['stock']['is_in_stock']
                      || config['special_price'] == null
                      || config['special_from_date'] == null 
                      || config['special_to_date'] == null) {
                    childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                    continue;
                  } 
                  
                  if (config['special_from_date'] != null && config['special_to_date'] != null) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    def from_millis = sf.parse(config['special_from_date']).getTime();
                    def to_millis = sf.parse(config['special_to_date']).getTime();
                    
                    if (!(timestampNow >= from_millis && timestampNow <= to_millis)) {
                      childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                      continue;
                    }
                  }
                  
                  def sale_fraction = 1 - (config['special_price'] / config['price']);
                  if (sale_fraction <= params.fraction) {
                    childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                    continue;
                  }
                  
                  childrenAreMatching.add(true);
                }
                return allEntriesAreTrue(childrenAreMatching);
              """,
              "params": {
                "timestampNow": 1617393889567,
                "fraction": 0.1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "min_score": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The response is as follows:

```json
{
  "took" : 15155,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2936,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [... hits here ...]
  }
}
```

Any idea why the query takes around 15 seconds?

Comment: Is `configurable_children` mapped as a `nested` field type?

Comment: @joesorocin is is mapped as an object with `properties` underneath.
I have added it to the post. It would be great if you have a lead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your intuition is right — you'll need to use a `for` loop if you want to check **all** of the array list objects.

Now, before I jump onto the iteration aspect, there's one important thing to know about arrays in Elasticsearch. When they're not defined as `nested`, their content [will be flattened](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects) and the relationships between the individual key/value pairs **will be lost**. As such, you should definitely adjust your mapping like so:

```json
{
  "vue_storefront_catalog_1_product_1614928276" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "configurable_children" : {
          "type": "nested",        <---
          "properties" : {
            "price" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and reindex your data to ensure that the `configurable_children` are treated as separate, standalone entities.

As soon as they're mapped as `nested`, you'll be able to retrieve just those children that do match your scripted condition:

```json
POST vue_storefront_catalog_1_product_1614928276/_search
{
  "_source": "configurable_children_that_match", 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "configurable_children",
      "inner_hits": {
        "name": "configurable_children_that_match"
      }, 
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": """
                    boolean hasSale = false;
                    
                    long timestampNow = new Date().getTime();
                    
                    if (doc.containsKey('configurable_children.special_from_date') && !doc['configurable_children.special_from_date'].empty) {
                      long timestampSpecialFromDate = doc['configurable_children.special_from_date'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
                      if (timestampSpecialFromDate > timestampNow) {
                       return false
                      }
                    } 
                    
                    if (doc.containsKey('configurable_children.special_to_date') && !doc['configurable_children.special_to_date'].empty) {
                      long timestampSpecialToDate = doc['configurable_children.special_to_date'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
                      if (timestampSpecialToDate < timestampNow) {
                        return false
                      }
                    }
                    
                    if (doc.containsKey('configurable_children.stock.is_in_stock') && doc['configurable_children.stock.is_in_stock'].value == false) {
                        return false
                    }
                    
                    if (1 - (doc['configurable_children.special_price'].value / doc['configurable_children.price'].value) > params.fraction) {
                      hasSale = true;
                    }
                    
                    return hasSale
                  """,
                  "params": {
                    "fraction": 0.1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Two things to note here:

1. The [`inner_hits` attribute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) of a [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) allows you to let Elasticsearch know that you're only interested in those children that truly matched. Otherwise, all `configurable_children` would be returned. When specified in the [`_source` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering), the original, full JSON document source would be skipped and only the named `inner_hits` would be returned.
2. Due to the distributed nature of ES, it's not recommended to use java's `new Date()`. I've explained the reasoning behind it [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62838813/8160318) to [How to get current time as unix timestamp for script use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837857/how-to-get-current-time-as-unix-timestamp-for-script-use). *You'll see me use a parametrized `now` in the query at the bottom of this answer.*

#### Moving on, it's important to mention that **nested objects are internally represented internally as separate subdocuments**.

A side effect of this fact is that once you're inside a `nested` query's context, you don't have access to other nested children of the very same document.

In order to mitigate this, it's customary to regularly keep the nested children in sync such that when you do flatten one of the objects' attributes for use on the top-level, you can use a simply iterate the respective doc values. This flattening is usually done through the `copy_to` feature which I illustrated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447956/how-to-iterate-through-a-nested-array-in-elasticsearch-with-filter-script/64452344#64452344) to [How to iterate through a nested array in elasticsearch with filter script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447956/how-to-iterate-through-a-nested-array-in-elasticsearch-with-filter-script)

In your particular use case, this'd mean that you'd, for instance, use `copy_to` on the field `stock.is_in_stock` which'd result in a top-level boolean array list which is easier to work with than an array list of objects.

**So far so good but you'd still be missing a way to filter based on the `special_dates`.**

Now, regardless of whether you're dealing with `nested` or regular `object` field types, accessing `params._source` in regular script queries doesn't work in ES since `v6.4`.

#### However, there's still one type of query that does support iterating the `_source` — enter `function_score` queries.

As stated in your question, you

> ..need to loop through the whole set of `configurable_children` to determine if it's a sale product..

With that being said, here's how my query below works:

1. The [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) typically generates a custom calculated score, but it can, with the help of `min_score`, be used as a boolean yes/no filter to exclude docs whose `configurable_children` do not fulfil a certain condition.
2. As the `configurable_children` are being iterated, each loop appends a boolean to `childrenAreMatching` which is then passed onto the `allEntriesAreTrue` helper which returns a 1 if they are, and a 0 if not.
3. The dates are parsed and compared with the parametrized `now`; the `fraction` is compared too. If, at any point, *some* condition fails, the loop jumps to the next iteration.

```json
POST vue_storefront_catalog_1_product_1614928276/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                // casting helper
                int allEntriesAreTrue(def arrayList) {
                  return arrayList.stream().allMatch(Boolean::valueOf) == true ? 1 : 0
                } 
                
                ArrayList childrenAreMatching = [];
                
                long timestampNow = params.timestampNow;
                
                ArrayList children = params._source['configurable_children'];
                
                if (children == null || children.size() == 0) {
                  return allEntriesAreTrue(childrenAreMatching);
                }
                
                for (config in children) {
                  if (!config['stock']['is_in_stock']
                      || config['special_price'] == null
                      || config['special_from_date'] == null 
                      || config['special_to_date'] == null) {
                    // nothing to do here...
                    childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                    continue;
                  } 
                  
                  SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                  def from_millis = sf.parse(config['special_from_date']).getTime();
                  def to_millis = sf.parse(config['special_to_date']).getTime();
                  
                  if (!(timestampNow >= from_millis && timestampNow <= to_millis)) {
                    // not in date range
                    childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                    continue;
                  }
                  
                  def sale_fraction = 1 - (config['special_price'] / config['price']);
                  if (sale_fraction <= params.fraction) {
                    // fraction condition not met
                    childrenAreMatching.add(false);
                    continue;
                  }
                  
                  childrenAreMatching.add(true);
                }
                
                // need to return a number because it's a script score query
                return allEntriesAreTrue(childrenAreMatching);
              """,
              "params": {
                "timestampNow": 1617393889567,
                "fraction": 0.1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "min_score": 1
    }
  }
}
```

All in all, only those documents, whose **all** `configurable_children` fulfil the specified conditions, would be returned.

---

P.S. If you learned something from this answer and want to learn more, I dedicated a [whole chapter to ES scripts](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/6-painless-scripting-c678b56cbec3430b913081023ff0d5db) in my [Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer Joe! It makes it so much more clear. I think I miss the fundamentals of Elasticsearch and will be looking into your handbook! Looks very nice and practical! 

I have modified the query a bit and posted it in the question above. The only downside now is that the complete query takes around 15/20 seconds! Is there a possibility to do something about this do you think?

Comment: You're welcome! Take your time with the book when you purchase it -- there's a bunch of interesting things in there :) Regarding the query speed -- scripts are typically the last resort. If there's any way of remodelling your data such that it's, for instance, child-based and the seldom-changed product attributes are duplicated for all children, go for it! The suggested script is essentially doing something that should really be done outside of ES. Hope it makes sense.