# Using NestedPath in Script Sort Elastic Search doesn't allow accessing outer properties

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested

I need to sort based on two logical part in script. For each document, min value ( HQ and offices distance from given distance) is calculated and returned for sorting.   Since I need to return only 1 value, I need to combine those scripts that calculate distance between hq and given location as well as multiple offices and given location.

I tried to combine those but Offices is nested property and Headquarter is non-nested property. If I use "NestedPath", somehow I am not able to access Headquarter property. Without "NestedPath", I am not able to use Offices property. here is the mapping:

```json
         "offices" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "coordinates" : {
                "type" : "geo_point",
                "fields" : {
                  "raw" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "index" : false
                  }
                },
                "ignore_malformed" : true
              },
              "state" : {
                "type" : "text"
              }
            }
          },
        "headquarters" : {
            "properties" : {
              "coordinates" : {
                "type" : "geo_point",
                "fields" : {
                  "raw" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "index" : false
                  }
                },
                "ignore_malformed" : true
              },
              "state" : {
                "type" : "text"
              }
            }
          }
```

And here is the script that I tried :

```json
 "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "nested" : {
          "path" : "offices"
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "params": {
            "lat": 28.9672,
            "lon": -98.4786
          },
          "source": "def hqDistance = 1000000;if (!doc['headquarters.coordinates'].empty){hqDistance = doc['headquarters.coordinates'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon) * 0.000621371;} def officeDistance= doc['offices.coordinates'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon) * 0.000621371; if (hqDistance < officeDistance) { return hqDistance; } return officeDistance;"
        },
        "type": "Number"
      }
    }
  ],
```

When I run the script, Headquarters logic is not even executed it seems, I get results only based on offices distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nested` fields operate in a separate context and their content cannot be accessed from the outer level, nor vice versa.

##### You can, however, access a document's [raw `_source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957242/8160318).

But there's a catch:

- See, when iterating under the `offices` nested path, you were able to call [`.arcDistance`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.0.0/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.GeoPoints.html#arcDistance(double,double)) because the `coordinates` are of type [`ScriptDocValues.GeoPoint`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-index-fielddata.html#painless-api-reference-shared-ScriptDocValues-GeoPoints).
- But once you access the raw `_source`, you'll be dealing with an unoptimized set of `java.util.ArrayList`s and `java.util.HashMap`s.

This means that even though you [can iterate an array list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-statements.html#_loop_statements):

```json
...
for (def office : params._source['offices']) {
   // office.coordinates is a trivial HashMap of {lat, lon}!
}
```

calculating geo distances won't be directly possible…

…unless you write your own `geoDistance` function -- which is [perfectly fine with `Painless`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-functions.html#painless-functions), but it'll need to be defined at the top of a script.

*No need to reinvent the wheel though: [Calculating distance between two points, using latitude longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude)*

##### A sample implementation

Assuming your documents look like this:

```json
POST my-index/_doc
{
  "offices": [
    {
      "coordinates": "39.9,-74.92",
      "state": "New Jersey"
    }
  ],
  "headquarters": {
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": 40.7128,
      "lon": -74.006
    },
    "state": "NYC"
  }
}
```

your sorting script could look like this:

```json
GET my-index/_search
{
   "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "order": "asc",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "params": {
            "lat": 28.9672,
            "lon": -98.4786
          },
          "source": """
            // We can declare functions at the beginning of a Painless script
            // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-functions.html#painless-functions
            
            double deg2rad(double deg) {
              return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
            }
            
            double rad2deg(double rad) {
              return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
            }
            
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694410/8160318
            double geoDistanceInMiles(def lat1, def lon1, def lat2, def lon2) {
              double theta = lon1 - lon2;
              double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
              dist = Math.acos(dist);
              dist = rad2deg(dist);
              return dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            }

            // start off arbitrarily high            
            def hqDistance = 1000000;

            if (!doc['headquarters.coordinates'].empty) {
              hqDistance = doc['headquarters.coordinates'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon) * 0.000621371;
            }
            
            // assume office distance as large as hq distance
            def officeDistance = hqDistance;
            
            // iterate each office and compare it to the currently lowest officeDistance
            for (def office : params._source['offices']) {
              // the coordinates are formatted as "lat,lon" so let's split...
              def latLong = Arrays.asList(office.coordinates.splitOnToken(","));
              // ...and parse them before passing onwards
              def tmpOfficeDistance = geoDistanceInMiles(Float.parseFloat(latLong[0]),
                                                         Float.parseFloat(latLong[1]),
                                                         params.lat,
                                                         params.lon);
              // we're interested in the nearest office...
              if (tmpOfficeDistance < officeDistance) {
                officeDistance = tmpOfficeDistance;
              }
            }
            
            if (hqDistance < officeDistance) {
              return hqDistance;
            }
            
            return officeDistance;
          """
        },
        "type": "Number"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Shameless plug: I dive deep into Elasticsearch scripting in a [dedicated chapter of my ES Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/6-painless-scripting-c678b56cbec3430b913081023ff0d5db).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. However my offices data is in this format :
```
"offices" : [
            {
              "coordinates" : "39.9,-74.92",
              "state" : "New Jersey"
            }
           ]
```
so passing coordinates as office.coordinates.lat and office.coordinates.lon in function gives me error as expected.
I tried to pass lat and Lon like this : office.coordinates[0], office.coordinates[1] And I am getting this error: "Attempting to address a non-array-like type [java.lang.String] as an array".  I appreciate your help here!

Comment: No prob. You'll need to parse your string array of coords... I updated my answer.

Comment: With SplitOnToken, I am getting this error : "dynamic method [java.lang.String, splitOnToken/1] not found". I think it's because my elastic version is old (v 6.7). Is there any workaround to this ?

Comment: indexOf and substring method worked for me. Your solution should work for anyone who has similar problem. Thank a lot to you. 
              def latLong = office.coordinates;
              def delPosition = latLong.indexOf(',');
              def latitude = latLong.substring(0, delPosition);
              def longitude = latLong.substring(delPosition +1);