# Elasticsearch Birth date aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I need my filter works like this:

```
18-24 | (16,635,890)
25-34 | (2,478,382)
35-44 | (1,129,493)
45-54 | (5,689,393)
55-64 | (4,585.933)
```

This is my ES mapping:

```
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "birthdate": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "m/d/yyyy"
    },
    "first_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do this with this mapping. I'm not very experienced in ES, I believe that to do this I need advanced knowledge in ES.

Also, I tried to do this to test, but without any aggregation :/

```
age: {
    terms: {
       field: 'birthdate'
    }
}

--------------------
"doc_count_error_upper_bound" => 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" => 0,
    "buckets" => [
                 {
                               "key" => 1072915200000,
                     "key_as_string" => "0/1/2004",
                         "doc_count" => 1
                 }
             ]
         },
```

I tried to read the documentation and search in some forums, but without success. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good candidate for this would be the [`ranges` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) but since your `birthdate` is formatted as a `date`, you'd need to calculate the age up until `now` *before* you proceeded to calculate the buckets. You can do so through a [Painless script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html#_script).

Putting it all together:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "price_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "script": {
          "source": "return (params.now_ms - doc['birthdate'].value.millis) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365",
          "params": {
            "now_ms": 1617958584396
          }
        }, 
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 18,
            "to": 24,
            "key": "18-24"
          },
          {
            "from": 25,
            "to": 34,
            "key": "25-34"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

would return:

```json
...
"aggregations" : {
  "price_ranges" : {
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "18-24",
        "from" : 18.0,
        "to" : 24.0,
        "doc_count" : 0
      },
      {
        "key" : "25-34",
        "from" : 25.0,
        "to" : 34.0,
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, 
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the current timestamp wasn't obtained through a dynamic `new Date()` call but rather hardcoded as a parametrized `now_ms` variable. This is the recommended way of doing date math due to the distributed nature of Elasticsearch. For more info on this, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837857/how-to-get-current-time-as-unix-timestamp-for-script-use/62838813#62838813) to [How to get current time as unix timestamp for script use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837857/how-to-get-current-time-as-unix-timestamp-for-script-use).

---

Shameless plug: if you're relatively new to ES, you might find my recently released [Elasicsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/) useful. One of the chapters is dedicated solely to aggregations and one to Painless scripting!